# pojo with embedded entity class

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

We have the following situation: an entity and a pojo in Objectify v5. 
As you can see, the entityclass has a reference to the pojo, like this:

```
@Entity
public class TestCustomer {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    TestIbj ibj;
}

class TestIbj {
    TestCustomer customer;
}
```

This fails with a StackOverflowError when we try to save it like this:

```
TestCustomer testCustomer = new TestCustomer();
OfyService.ofy().save().entity(testCustomer).now();
```

Error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2772)
at java.lang.Class.isCheckMemberAccessOverridden(Class.java:2214)
at java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Class.java:2233)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1854)
at...
```

Our question is: Why is this not allowed/failing? If we change the pojo into an Entity, it works fine, but we don't understand why that is..

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

StackoverflowError almost always means that there is an unbounded recursion. It's the case in your code as well:

```
@Entity
public class TestCustomer {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    TestIbj ibj;  // TestCustomer contains TestIbj
}

class TestIbj {
    TestCustomer customer;  // TestIbj contains TestCustomer (which further contains TestIbj.. and so on)
}
```

Due to this circular dependency (shown in code above), objectify will never be able to construct object graph.